# Science fiction/fantasy book I read 50 years ago. Took place on the planet Venus

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, mermaids

I remember loving this book when I was in middle school It took place on the planet Venus. It was all ocean. There were sea horses (their leader was named Belleraphon) and porpoises and mermaids. A group of siblings go to Venus with their uncle(?) and while exploring become involved in a quest to rescue a mermaid from a monster that keeps her locked up in cave (bowl?) with a lid that only he can remove. There was also something about the mermaid's comb and a mountain (reef?) that had chameleon-like abilities.

Answer (score 6):

*[Encounter Near Venus](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1103296)* by Leonard Wibberley (1967)

From the [Kirkus review](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/leonard-wibberley-36/encounter-near-venus/):

> Four children (two brothers -- two sisters) are sent to their
> mysterious Uncle Bill's house in a Colorado wasteland for an eight
> week summer vacation. Before their plane lands they have managed to
> spot two flying saucers (one pink). Equally colorful adventures are in
> store as they discover that Uncle Bill was a passenger on the pink one
> and is a frequenter of ""Nede,"" a satellite of Venus. It seems that
> Bill, previously not a fancier of Children, was totally unprepared for
> their visit, let alone their discovery of the tinkerbelle lights that
> communicate in Morse code. There's nothing left for him to do but to
> take them with him on an important mission to Nede where they find
> Wibberley's version of Fantasia complete with mermaids, baby gorgons,
> Cockney centaurs, Irish sea elephants, dolphins and a nefarious
> serpent named Ka, the Smiler.